# How to "unrevert" a previously reverted commit?

Tags: git, git-revert

Imagine the following scenario:

Code that shouldn't have been merged to the integration branch needs to be reverted.  However, you can't just reset, since other commits have happened since then.  Further, you may want to re-apply that commit at a later time.

It's easy enough to use `git revert` to apply a reverse commit.  However, what happens when we want to commit that change (from a feature branch, for instance)?  Do you just re-merge the branch?  Will that work, since technically the code has already been merged?

What do you do when you are finally ready to accept that merge?

Answer (score 8):

Just revert the revert commit.

```
git revert HASH_OF_REVERT_COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your scenario correctly, you want to revert the branch which was merged to the integration branch.

---

In that case, for example,

```
git <your_branch> merged to master, pushed to origin/master.
```

You want to revert the commit what you pushed to origin.

## Reverting the merge commit/ single commit.

This will revert the single commit and also used to revert merge commits.

**Example:**

```
git revert -m 1 <commit-ID>
Finished one revert.
[master xxxxxxx] Revert "Merge branch 'xx/your_branch'"
 10 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 12 deletions(-)
```

git revert will introduce the new commit. You need to commit the changes and push it to origin/master or corresponding origin/branch.

## Reverting the revert

What if you decided to re-merge the stuff, its regression is fixed?

**Example:**

```
git revert <commit-ID>
Finished one revert.
[master xxxxxxx] Revert "Merge branch 'xx/your_branch'"
 10 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

After doing this you fixed the regression introduced that was in the branch, reverted out before. Later, you can merge that branch into origin

Comment: A more elaborate explanation.  We have a develop branch that has all the merged changes from feature branches.  We want to do a release, but some of those commits are determined to either have issues, or simply don't yet want to release.  Obviously, we can cherry pick the commits we want, but I don't like that because it doesn't show up in a history graph, so the other option is to merge develop with release, and reverting the commits we don't want.  Now, later we DO want to release those commits.

Comment: So maybe, yes, it is as simple as reverting the revert commit.

Comment: Well, if you want to release from the develop branch, in that case, what if you want to revert 15 commits?  In that case, its bit tedious. However, revert will add one extra commit in the branch. Perhaps, you can try to merge the specific commit to your release branch but this has an equal amount of work when you do the revert. The straight forward way is reverting revert commit in your case if it's not more commits.